# Memory consumption of MultiBinding in WPF seems extreme

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

First in short the background:
We have a TreeView where we broke the virtualization, that lead to a huge increase of memory consumption up to an OutOfMemoryException. While this is certainly the core issue and will be resolved I noted something different when analyzing the problem: The memory consumption of our MultiBindings seems to be huge to the point where I would not believe it!

Therefore I want to ask here if anyone has experienced the same and more importantly if this is normal or some issue I have with my code.

First the binding in question in it's TreeListViewCellDataTemplate:

```
<treeListView:TreeListViewCellDataTemplate
                    TemplateEnum="{x:Static treeListView:DataTemplateEnum.Something}">
                    <Border d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=treeListView:SomethingValueViewModel}"
                            Background="{Binding Path=Index, Converter={StaticResource IndexToBackgroundConverter}, Mode=OneTime}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="1,0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CaseLikeMultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="State" Mode="OneTime"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static treeListView:SomethingValueState.UnInitialized}"/>
                                    <Binding Source="?"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static treeListView:SomethingValueState.Initialized}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Value"  Mode="OneTime"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static treeListView:SomethingValueState.Known}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Value" Mode="OneTime"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static treeListView:SomethingValueState.Conflicted}"/>
                                    <Binding Source="≠"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static treeListView:SomethingValueState.Unbounded}"/>
                                    <Binding Source="≠"/>
                                    <Binding Source="?"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </treeListView:TreeListViewCellDataTemplate>
```

I measured memory consumption with the above template and the same template with the `<TextBlock.Text>...</TextBlock.Text>`  simply commented out. On 350 instances of the template, I get ~13MB more memory consumption than with the template commented out. That is around 37KB per MultiBinding instance!

My measurement method is somewhat makeshift as I simply compare managed memory consumption of the whole test program. For the commented out case, that is ~79MB and with the MultiBinding active that is ~92MB. I tried to make this more reliable by running both measurements multiple times and the results are comparatively stable, so I am rather confident in the results.

I searched a while for sources to MultiBinding memory consumption but could find nothing, which confused me, given my results.

In the end the question is: Is it normal that MultiBinding consumes so much memory? Is there some issue with my XAML? Is there some way to optimize it without replacing the MultiBinding?

**Edit**: Thank you for your responses!

To clarify my question, I am not looking for a solution for this specific MultiBinding. I am aware that I can replace the MultiBinding and use view model code (somewhat a break of MVVM) or a specific converter.
I want to know why and especially **when** MultiBindings consume so much memory. If I don't know when I can safely use MultiBinding I have to either stop using them, measure each instance or rely on my gut feeling.

Lets have a more classic example:

```
<TextBlock.Foreground>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolToForegroundConverter}">
         <Binding Path="IsSourcePathValid"/>
         <Binding Path="IsSelected"/>
     </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Foreground>
```

The consumption is ~ 0.7MB on 350 instances, which is ~2kb per instance. That still seems astonishingly much to me but it will not scale out of hand as fast and there is obviously still quite the difference to the more offensive example. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Are these your real bindings? I mean `<Binding Source="?"/>` etc.  seem really odd.

Comment: I would remove all those bindings and use a single converter, parse it once. Otherwise Binding has to resolve all of those paths and sources, one by one. I have never seen anything like this and if this was a human body, I would advise you to see a doctor as soon as you can.

Comment: I think you should do whatever the converter is intended to do elsewhere. As you build the viewmodel or via logic in the viewmodel and feed your data changes into the viewmodels. There's nothing inherent to a multibinding consumes loads of memory though.